# Alert index of clicked link in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, closures, alert

Need to write function to alert index of clicked link in the document.
For example:

```
 [html]
 <body>
    Links:<br/>
    <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
    <a href="//www.facebook.com">Facebook</a><br/>
    <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
  </body>  
 [/html]
```

My function:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = as.length; i>= 0; i--) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
      alert(i);
    }
  }
```

Please help me fix bugs

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You are not looking to alert any contents from the link, but the actual position compared to other links yes? Like facebook would avert 1, yahoo would alert 0? Yes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

> The actual event occurs sometime in the future after your for loop has already finished running and thus its index is at the last value. You need to create some sort of closure that preserves the value of `i` uniquely for each event handler so they each have access to their own value. There are several different ways to do that, but all involve passing the `i` value to a function for each event handler.

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/7nwpx123/)

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0, j=as.length; i<j; i++) {
    var link = as[i];
    (function(i){
        link.onclick = function() {
            alert (i);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: what about `for (i = as.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {` instead of `for (var i=0, j=as.length; i<j; i++) {`

Comment: Sure, you could use either :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you linked jquery:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/bnsssjLj/)

```
$('a').each(function(a, b){
    $(this).attr('id', a).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use the `id` to stock the index then you can create a `data-index`:

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/bnsssjLj/1/)

```
$('a').each(function(a, b){
    $(this).attr('data-index', a).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr('data-index'));
    });
});
```